# My Script that sorts Videos by their tags isn't functioning at all

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that basically says when you type a valid video tag it prints out "Found Tag" to the console. This is useful for organization / sorting purposes. The bad thing is, the code dosen't work. How come, and what can I do to improve the script?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const vids = [
    {
      tags : ['technology','programming','life','2020'],
      url : "videos/tech.mp4",
      name : "7 Amazing Technology",
    }
  ]
  const search = document.getElementById("Search")
  const btnSearch = document.getElementById("btnSearch")

  btnSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let videoTag = search.value;
    for (let x = 0; x < vids.length; x++)
    {
      for (let y of vids.tags)
      {
        if (vids[x].tags == videoTag)
        {
          console.log("Found Tag!")
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <input id = "Search" type = "text" placeholder = "Search videos">
    <input id = "btnSearch" type = 'button' value = "Search">
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

TL;DR: For now I only have one added video, but in the future I plan on adding more, so please have a solution that would loop through all elements of the objects, and find the video tags'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your indexing is slightly off in your nested looping:

```js
  btnSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let videoTag = search.value;
    for (let x = 0; x < vids.length; x++)
    {
      for (let y = 0; y < vids[x].tags.length; y++)
      {
        if (vids[x].tags[y] == videoTag)
        {
          console.log("Found Tag!")
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: When I did it myself it didn't work, but when I copied/pasted your solution it worked. Wow. Can you explain what all did you change and elaborate on it?

Comment: Sure, the issue is in you second loop. You want to loop through tags only on the vids[x] array element, not on the entire array. Then I changed your next loop to make sure you were comparing videoTag with tags[y]